# Large Data Initial Setup Pattern for Task Parallel Library

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, large-data

For those of you looking to parallelize your compute-intensive algorithms, let me point you to this document on common patterns leveraging the Task Parallel Library of .NET 4 and beyond:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222

However, there is one pattern, that I think reasonably common, that I have that is not covered in that otherwise awesome document...

I have say 100 rows in a DataTable that have a set of inputs in N columns for which I need to compute some outputs in M columns.  Each row can be computed independently, so it seems prime for parallelization.

HOWEVER, to do that computation, I need to first build a massive data structure.  Once built for a row, I can then simply reset it to use it for another row.  So, I don't want to rebuild it from scratch for each row... that takes much longer than doing the reset.  But the parallel computations cannot share that data structure as they will each be modifying it... rather, they each need their own.

Soooo, algorithmically, what I need to do is start a thread for each processor core that I have available that first builds its own massive data structure.  Then it should compute a row, reset, compute another row, reset, and so on until there are no more rows to compute.

The Task Parallel Library has all the smarts to manage such a process... but I have yet to find any example of this scenario, where I need each thread to do a massive data build, compute, reset, compute, reset, and so on until done.

That would seem to be a reasonably common pattern... can anyone point me to an example of how the Task Parallel Library of .NET 4 and beyond supports that pattern??

Comment: That's a common smell, not a common pattern. If you have to "clean and reuse" the same structure, you'll need locking. Bad idea. Why do you need a prefabricated structure anyway? What's the benefit? Either you'll have to replace all values (just create a new one then), or you are talking about constant values.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you think is solved by reusing structures? Are you trying to reduce memory consumption? Allocations? You could use techniques to avoid allocations (eg use regex instead of string splitting of files), or use buffer pools to reuse buffers.

Comment: I won't need locking because I plan to have each thread build their own instance of that base structure.  Think of it as the model of the world.  Then each row contains what happens in that world (the input) and then needs to do a huge analysis to determine the results which go back into that row.  No locking needed.  The issue is that if I have 4 cores and 1000 rows, I want to build that base model of the world just 4 times and have each thread clean and reuse its model 250 times.  (My current sequential implementation builds the world model once, and cleans and reuses it 1000 times.)

Comment: Reusing the world model saves time.  Imagine it takes 10 minutes to build that base model, 2 minutes to use it to compute the results of a row, and 1 minute to clean it.  My sequential would take 10 + 1000 * (2 + 1) = 3010 minutes.  If I parallelize it by queueing 1000 tasks to run on 4 cores that each build model and analyze, then it will take (10 + 2) * 1000 / 4 = 3000 minutes.  Given extra overhead, a  net loss. If I parallelize it as I suggest, it will take 10 minutes for all 4 to build base model plus (2 + 1) * 1000 / 4 = 760 min... pretty close to 4x speedup. How do I set that up in TPL?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer that I have come up with is this...
Please let me know if you have better... or if you can see flaws in this...

I think I need to call Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, ...) and have that code build the base structure and then start processing rows by doing Interlocked.Increment on a shared rowIndex until all the rows are processed.

In that way, the base structure is built at most once for each processor and then reused... but if that starts consuming too much memory or other resources, then the Parallel.For can choose to run fewer than Environment.ProcessorCount tasks at once.  True?

Is there a better way?